# Microsoft Bot Framework - Webchat text as html

Tags: botframework

I'm using Microsoft Bot Framework (Node JS), with Webchat channel.
The webchat shows HTML tags as plain text `("<br> bla bla <br>")` while I want it to be rendered.

[image]

There is any way to make it render the HTML tags?

Comment: Where is this being displayed? On a browser?

Comment: You need to read the docs from the chat service you are using. This has nothing to do with the bot framework...

Comment: Right. Webchat is the browser chat platform of Microsoft.

Comment: I dont know much about it but seems like youre going to have to use markdown. Probably you can convert html to markdown(*plenty* libraries exist). This link will probably help you [HERE](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#markdown)

Comment: Sorry? The Botframework-webchat is a platform which MSBF offers to use.

Comment: I think renaming the tags would be better. `botframework` refers to a lot of things.

Comment: @KidDoesCodingAndHasNoFriends Thanks but I've already changed the mark-it preferences according to [this](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/09/07/html-not-supported-web-chat/) blog. Seems like the incoming messages doesn't pass thought markit.

Comment: I think it is just a problem with the html you are trying to display. Try to check if it is valid and also all tags can not be rendered like `<hr>`.

Comment: The problem is not in the HTML, Although there is a mistake in the shown picture (extra h5 tag)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Bot Framework supports only 2 types of text format:

- Markdown
- XML (The textFormat xml is supported only by the Skype channel.)

Hence it is normal that you don't have what you wanted.

See documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-inspector#text-formatting

As a consequence, you have to transform your html to markdown to get your intended output, but you will be limited to the capabilities of markdown and the restrictions of markdown rendering in the channels.

You can check markdown rendering by channel here: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/WebChat?f=Markdown&e=example1