# Issue in rendering HTML Table on Skype for business on mobile device

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, botframework, skype

I've created Bot using Microsoft's bot services ( Bot framework) using nodeJs.

Its working fine when for plain text, but when i tried to return HTML table using below method

```
  eg.

  var tableHTML = '<table style="padding:20px;border:1px solid black;  border-collapse: collapse;" border=1 border-collapse=collapse><tr style="background-color:#c6c6c6"><th>Countries</th><th>Capitals</th><th>Population</th><th>Language</th></tr><tr><td>USA</td><td> Washington D.C.</td><td>309 million</td><td>English</td></tr><tr><td>Sweden</td><td>Stockholm</td><td>9 million</td><td>Swedish</td></tr></table>';

      var message = {
      type: 'message',
      textFormat: 'xml',
      text: tableHTML
    };
    session.send(message);
```

It worked for me on skype for business desktop APP , but not working on skype for business mobile APP ( it returns nothing )

Currently i'm facing issue while rending HTML table for mobile devices on skype for business

Skype for business mobile app supports HTML in bot ??

Please provide if anyone have solution for this

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should try with textFormat: 'html' ?

Comment: @Sparw no that's not a valid textFormat value in Bot Framework

Comment: Even if this linked question is about Webchat channel, the reply I provided is still valid for your question, kind of duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148447/microsoft-bot-framework-webchat-text-as-html/48149001#48149001

Comment: @Sparw type html is not there in documentation for bot framework

Answer (score 0):

Skype for business mobile clients **do not** support HTML or markdown formats.  This is a pain point for many customers I encourage you to reach out to them via their [uservoice](https://www.skypefeedback.com/) and request this feature.

Format rendering will be channel-specific and you need to determine what formats a channel supports ahead of time.