# Is it possible to use html tags on Microsoft QnA Maker replies?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

It is possible to use html tags on Microsoft QnAMaker replies?

I already try to create new line with `\n\n` but it is not working on webchat or skype.
Moreover, how can I create bullets or numbering on QnA Maker?

Comment: How did you try to create your lines with `\n\n`? It's working on my side for doing new lines. For the other part of the question, you have to use markdown (see my previous reply here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148447/microsoft-bot-framework-webchat-text-as-html/)

Comment: hi @NicolasR, thank you, maybe i missing that documentation, that what i really need. once again, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Bot Framework - Webchat text as html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148447/microsoft-bot-framework-webchat-text-as-html)

Answer (score 0):

Currently Microsoft QnAMaker service send the HTML tags added in answer as escaped HTML. A code like the following

```
<b> bold text </b>
```

will be sent as escaped HTML like given below

```
&lt;b&gt; bold text &lt;/b&gt;
```

I faced the same issue when we trained QNAMaker answers with HTML formatting and this content was consumed using APIs. This is the response received from Microsoft support team when reported this issue.

> We are aware of this issue with our answering service. We'll work on a
>   fix and deploy it in our next update.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles upon this issue, QnAMaker now supports [markdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-markdown-format), so you can just use a line break in your `.lu` file (or a literal `\n` in you `.json` file) to create line breaks. You can also just use `-` to create bullet points