# How to avoid pronounciation of ' in the text when speaking it

Tags: botframework, text-to-speech

I am building a bot with speaking services and connected with QnA services. I have some text to be spoken with single quote in it.

When the bot speaks the text, for example: "I don't have a family".

It pronounces it as:

I don backslash t have a family.

How to avoid such reading in speech service. I tried to find out some SSML markup tags but it didn't work with me.

can someone help to figure it out what shall I try?

thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Are you sure it really is "I don't have a family"? According to your output, I would expect that there is a real backslash in the resulting text. Might be a wired parsing before outputting it to speech. Could you please check? In my experience things like "don't", "wouldn't", "haven't" work well.

Comment: @SebastianZolg Hi, I have an answer from QnA which I am adding to an adaptive card. So when I tried to escape the single quote and added it there. I just used string replace function to do this: translatedBotAnswer.Replace("'", "\'"); But I guess it is adding one more \ . thanks. I will try to do this better.

Comment: Great it helped. Would you mind upvoting my comment?

Comment: As this often happens with responses from QnA in other scenarios, I answered your question with such a hint. Would you mind accepting it as the answer to your initial question?

Comment: Hi there! Are you still okay with my answer? Would you mind marking it so? Thanks

Comment: Hi, would you mind marking my answer as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it speaks "*I don backslash t have a family*" then the input text **does** contain a backslash instead of **'**. Words like *haven't, wouldn't, don't* are correctly interpreted by text to speech.

As pointed out in the comments, the questioner is using QnA maker and doing some string replacements before outputting it.

Due to the nature of QnA maker editor, such things happen quite often as QnA maker editor supports a few formatting options as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071383/is-it-possible-to-use-html-tags-on-microsoft-qna-maker-replies).

Whenever using QnA maker responses and routing it directly to a voice-enabled channel, make sure that you escape it in some ways.